# ElasticSearch: high cardinality aggregation circuit breaker

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an app where the user is allowed to perform aggregations on high-cardinality fields. Unfortunately, such aggregations can be very slow. For one particular field with a cardinality of 4 million, it takes 7 seconds.

Such aggregations do not yield useful results. I'd like to terminate them quickly and just return an error message for that particular aggregation that says "too many values".

Is this possible?

ElasticSearch does support some circuit breakers: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html, but I don't see one that would apply to a single aggregation within a larger query containing multiple aggregations. Plus, these apply to memory usage, not execution speed.

Comment: Do you need to return an error? Can't you just limit the size?

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris The size is already limited. It still takes 7 seconds to execute. I'd like to terminate the execution early to speed up the query.

Comment: You can set a timeout for this aggregation on your application. Which client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You won't know in advance how many seconds an aggregation is going to take -- there are too many variables at play.

You can assess where the spike begins -- be it 1M, 4M etc and then either display the warning *before* the request is sent or arbitrarily after x units of time when there's no response yet... There are [various](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.x/_timeouts.html) client [ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/request-timeout.html) of doing that.

Once a request is being handled in ES, I don't know of any way to stop it until it resolves or times out.